# How do I create an array based on an observable

Tags: knockout.js

This is a follow-up to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982614/knockout-create-array-in-viewmodel).

I have 1 observable property (pageNumber) mapped from an JSON object structured like this: `requestData.settings.pageNumber`

I want to create a pager using Knockout as in the following code:

```html
<ul class="pagination">

    <!-- ko foreach: Paging() -->
        <li data-bind="click: function () { $root.changePage($data) }" class="active">
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data"></a>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->

</ul>
```

The paging is now an array that in my code won't update. Please help me find out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Assuming Paging is an observableArray: Have you tried to remove () in your foreach? <!-- ko foreach: Paging -->

Comment: Why should I do that? the thing i wanna achieve(in pseudo): array = new range(page-5, page+5);
if the pagenumber observable changes....the array should change.

Comment: Please include your relevant ViewModel logic in the question as well, try to make a [repro](http://sscce.org) (maybe even also include the same code in a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)). This will make your question a lot clearer, and makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a computed like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.currentPage = ko.observable(6);

    this.paging = ko.computed(function() {
        var currentPage = this.currentPage();

        return range(currentPage-5, currentPage+5,1);
    }, this);
};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q96a5/) with not much more

The `range` code is taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3895521/168097)